# How preprocess and post-process at using TensorFlow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, input, keras, preprocessor, tensorflow-serving

I am designing a sentence classification service using TensorFlow Serving.

I succeeded boot up a docker server, request a prediction, and received a prediction results.

My model's has two input layers and one output layer.

```
lexical_input (InputLayer)      [(None, 1000)]       0 
phoneme_input (InputLayer)      [(None, 150)]        0                  
... ... ... ... ... ... 
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 104)          43368       concatenate[0][0]
```

Now my service's input format and output format are vectors.

Client(user) has to vectorize their input string, and they have to do argmax and map to get a label.

I want my clients request with plane sentence not vector, and can get a label as a prediction results.

I already have functions to vectorize input sentence and get a label from prediction result vector.

I don't know how can I connect my functions and my model.

As a result of searching, I had to do something when using tf.saved_model.simple_save().

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use another webserver like flask to do the pre(post)-processing. You can do a http or gRPC call from flask to tf serving after pre-processing and use the response to do post processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Like you told me, we already have a WAS for API and first level preprocessing (such as Morpheme Analysis). We can vectorize and label at that WAS, but we concern about a synchronization in vocabulary, model, and labelMap. In a side of synchro, we think only one deployment is more safer than two deployments (vocabulary and label map to WAS, and model to Serving server). So I am finding a function of TF Serving to pre(post)-processing.  Thanks to your opinion. It was a good chance to review our service architecture.